# how to transforming a matrix to reduced row echelon form by using C#?

Tags: c#, matrix

I want to create a project like this by the use of C#:
http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?c=rref

I already create a form, but I don't know what is code behind this? I think there are a lots of formula?
Does anyone know the complete codes in making the matrix? I think I need the class below?

```
MultiplyRow() for multiplying a whole row by an integer/fraction/double.
AddRow() for adding multiple of one row to another.
InterchangeRow() for interchanging two rows.
Concatenate() to concatenate two matrices column wise (this function is helpful when we want to create augmented matrix for solving equations).
Adjoint() to find adjoint of the matrix.
Transpose() to return transpose of the matrix.
Determinent() there are two functions, one finds the determinant by the common minor method while the other is a very fast. algorithm that makes use of reduced echelon form to find the determinant.
Inverse() there are two functions, one finds the inverse by the common adjoints method while the other uses reduced echelon form method to find it. Obviously, the second one is far more efficient that the first one which slows mainly due to recursion.
EchelonForm() can be useful in equation solving by Gaussian Elimination method.
ReducedEchelonForm() can be useful in equation solving by Gauss-Jordan method.
```

What is the codes inside each class? Please help me. This is very important for me in my studies.Thanks

Comment: We can´t do your homework for you, please make an effort and if you get stuck and cant find the answer anywhere stackoverflow is the place to be. There are many tutorials on how to start coding in windows forms, good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an appropriate question for SO, since you're basically asking "Do my homework"

However, I think you'll find help on GitHub: https://github.com/mirhagk/matrixreducer looks like a pretty relevant source to check out!